# why could macros not understand a Dict parameter?

Tags: dictionary, macros, julia, expression

```
macro test1(name,arg)
    println(arg.args[2])
    typeof(arg.args[2])
end 

@test1 test1 (
  (arg1, (:max=>10))
)
```

I have the macro above and I'm trying to pass a Dict parameter as the second parameter. But the problem is that I cannot access it. The macro will always interpret the second parameter as an expression, and when I try to access `arg.args[2].args` it shows:

```
Vector{Any} (alias for Array{Any, 1})
```

so I don't know how to pass the Dict as it is.

I just want to get the second argument like:

```
Dict{Symbol, Int64} with 1 entry:
  :max => 10
```

Comment: Macros operate on code not on values! If you want to operate on values use a function. What exactly would you like your macro to do?

Comment: I want to pass that dict to a function as keyword value parameter.

Comment: macros work at compile time rather than runtime. Hence whatever you pass you will see as an `Expr` as in the answer below. Perhaps this post is helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64112110/julia-how-do-i-use-kwargs-in-macros/64113990#64113990

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because macros work on code before the code is compiled. Source code is first parsed to `Symbol`s, literals (integers, floats, strings, etc), or `Expr` (expressions). At this point, all expressions contain only these three things.** After the macro is done and returns an expression, that expression is compiled into runtime code where more complicated objects like `Dict`s can exist.

The code below illustrates the difference before and after compiling. Note how `1+5` and `Dict()` were expressions in the macro body, but is afterward evaluated to an `Int64` and a `Dict`.

```
                             # splat arbitrary number of Expr
macro peekExpr(expr1, expr2, expr3tuple...)
    println(typeof(expr1), "   ", expr1)
    println(typeof(expr2), "   ", expr2)
    println(typeof(expr3tuple), "   ", expr3tuple)
    :($expr1, $expr2, $expr3tuple)
end

evaluated = @peekExpr 1+5 Dict() Int64 10 max::Int64
#= printout
Expr   1 + 5
Expr   Dict()
Tuple{Symbol,Int64,Expr}   (:Int64, 10, :(max::Int64))
=#

for item in evaluated  println(typeof(item), "   ", item)  end
#= printout
Int64   6
Dict{Any, Any}   Dict{Any, Any}()
Tuple{Symbol,Int64,Expr}   (:Int64, 10, :(max::Int64))
=#
```

**PS: Bear in mind that `Expr` can contain other objects if you interpolate runtime objects into them (`x = Dict(); :(a in $x).args[end]` vs `:(a in Dict()).args[end]`). It's just that macros do not work at a phase where it can access runtime objects. `@peekExpr $x` will only see a `Expr(:$, :x)`.